# Rails run code from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in 'JobplansController`. It creates`workorder`and`tasks`based on templates called`jobplan`and`jobtask`.

```
  def copy_to_workorder
  @jobplan = Jobplan.find(params[:id]) # find original jobplan
  wo_attrs =  @jobplan.attributes
  wo_attrs.merge!({jobplan_id: @jobplan.id })
  wo_attrs.delete('woschedule_id')
  workorder = Workorder.create(wo_attrs)

  @jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
    jobtask_attrs = jobtask.attributes
    jobtask_attrs.delete('jobplan_id')
    jobtask_attrs.merge!({workorder_id: workorder.id })
    Task.create(jobtask_attrs)
  end

  redirect_to @jobplan, notice: 'Project was successfully created.'
end
```

It runs fine using this button:

```
<%= link_to 'Create Workorder', copy_to_workorder_jobplans_path(:id => @jobplan.id), :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

`Jobplans` have a many_to_many relationship with `woschedule`.  The `woschedule` is being used to schedule the creation of `workorders` based on the `jobplans`.

I'm trying to add code to the `woschedule` controller.  This is what I'm trying:

```
  def run_jobplans
    @woschedule = Woschedule.find(params[:id])
    @woschedule.jobplans.each do |jobplan|
      copy_to_workorder_jobplans_path(jobplan)
    end

    redirect_to @woschedule, notice: 'Jobplans were run successfully.'
  end
```

The button I'm using to run `run_jobplans` is this:

```
<%= link_to 'Run Jobplans', run_jobplans_woschedules_path(:id => @woschedule.id), :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

It is executing the code, but no new `workorders` get created.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE !

I moved the code to the applications controller:

```
  def jobplan_to_workorder
@jobplan = Jobplan.find(params[:id]) # find original jobplan
wo_attrs =  @jobplan.attributes
wo_attrs.merge!({jobplan_id: @jobplan.id })
wo_attrs.delete('woschedule_id')
workorder = Workorder.create(wo_attrs)

@jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
  jobtask_attrs = jobtask.attributes
  jobtask_attrs.delete('jobplan_id')
  jobtask_attrs.merge!({workorder_id: workorder.id })
  Task.create(jobtask_attrs)
end
end
```

This works in the `jobplan` controller - where I'm creating from one `jobplan`:

But, how do I pass the `:id` when executing from `woschedule` controller? `woschedule has_many :jobplans`:

```
  def run_jobplans
   @woschedule = Woschedule.find(params[:id])
   @woschedule.jobplans.each do |jobplan|
    jobplan_to_workorder(:id => jobplan.id)
   end
   redirect_to @woschedule, notice: 'Jobplans were run successfully.'
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy your main method to application_controller and remove some of the codes which are not common.

application_controller.rb

```
def copy_to_workorder_jobplans(parameter)
  ...
end
```

x_controller.rb

```
def a
  ...
  copy_to_workorder_jobplans(parameter)
  redirect_to a_path
end
```

y_controller.rb

```
def b
  ...
  copy_to_workorder_jobplans(parameter)
  redirect_to b_path
end
```

Comment: How do I pass the parameter for the jobplan? Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the logic you're referencing in both controller methods to a helper and call it independently.